¿Es posible actualizar diferentes valores en un campo según diferentes criterios de otro campo todo en una misma consulta de actualización?
Tengo la siguiente consulta de actualización sencilla
UPDATE Territorios SET Territorios.zona = "1" 
WHERE (((territorios.direccion)="calle 51"));

Pero necesito que en la misma consulta de actualización tenga en cuenta otros criterios del propio campo dirección y según ellos actualice otros valores en el campo zona.
Ej:
UPDATE Territorios SET Territorios.zona = "2" 
WHERE (((territorios.direccion)="calle 66"));

y así sucesivamente con diversas calles actualice los números de zonas de ahí que necesite si es posible que todo lo pueda hacer con una sola consulta para no abarrotarme de ellas. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo quedaría la instrucción en SQL si fuera posible esto?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! dependiendo la base, podrias usar un case. Tambien podes crear otra tabla y usar un update desde la otra tabla.. pero por lo que pone tu pregunta, imposible decirte...

Puedes buscar información sobre el uso de Case, para tu base de datos. Update territorios set zona = case when ....

En access es posible, mediante la función Switch
UPDATE Territorios SET zona = switch(direccion="calle 51",1, direccion="calle 66", 2) WHERE direccion IN ("calle 51", "calle 66");

En este caso hay que modificar el where para ampliar la cantidad de direcciones a actualizar y en el Switch establecemos las condiciones individuales.

Quizás debí aclarar que uso access. No tuve éxito me sale el siguiente error: Error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresión de consulta 'CASE WHEN territorios.direccion='calle 51' THEN 1
WHEN territorios.direccion='calle 66' THEN 2
ELSE -1
END
WHERE territorios.direccion IN ('calle 51', 'calle 66' );

access lamentablemente tiene un set muy reducido de clausulas SQL, ahí edité mi respuesta.
